# Is there any open source schematics for M.2 to USB Type C adapter?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, usb-c, sata

Here are some pictures of what I meant.

Unfortunately there are no labels near the components.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You mean actual NVMe, transported as PCIe over a Thunderbolt 3 or TB4 link, or as alternate mode in USB-C via a USB-C cable, so that the device is actually an NVMe to the host system? Or do you mean NVMe, transported as USB Mass storage device over USB-C? Or do just mean an M.2 form factor SSD, speaking SATA to be represented as USB Mass storage Device via USB via USB-C cabling?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Exactly this, i want that the M.2 will be represented as USB Mass Storage. "Or do just mean an M.2 form factor SSD, speaking SATA to be represented as USB Mass storage Device via USB via USB-C cabling".

Comment: ah, then please remove the NVMe from your question!

Comment: @MarcusMüller so M.2 is the right term?

Comment: M.2 SATA would be the right term – there's NVMe (i.e., PCIe) and SATA transported over M.2 (which has different *keying* to signify what it carries).

Comment: Note that a SATA-only controller wouldn't be able to speak to SSDs that only talk NVMe (PCIe), and vice versa, a PCIe-only (NVMe-only) controller won't be able to speak SATA SSDs. The board you show *probably* has a dual-mode controller, which can do both, assuming they use the M-keying here correctly. But I can't read the marking on the chip.

Comment: It might be a RTL9210B-GB, but then an open hardware design will not help you at all, unless you have a friend at a large company who's willing to get you in contact with Realtek's sales department and you've got funds to buy a couple 10s of thousands of these, at least…

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes it's a  RTL9210B-GB. Thank you for the advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pictured device is not "USB to m.2 adapter". It is USB-C to m.2 bridge (converter?) with specific "M-key", which means it is to support only NVMe mass storage modules. Not SATA, the SATA uses a different m.2 key and usually these bridges are not compatible. The pictured device likely uses [RealTek RTL9210 bridge](https://www.realtek.com/en/products/connected-media-ics/item/rtl9210b-cg). The other popular bridge to translate USB-C into NVMe is [JMicron JMS583](https://www.jmicron.com/news/detail/21) chip.

If you are looking to make reuse of older SATA NGFF devices, there are other types of bridges that use different controller IC, and the m.2 connector should have "M+B key".

And yes, there are several types of devices that collectively called m.2, they are keyed differently, and can support USB3, USB2, and various other serial protocols.
see [this source](https://www.techtarget.com/searchstorage/definition/M2-SSD):
[image]

And no, you cannot "breadboard" this kind of devices, since they use 5-10GHz signal rates and require VERY CAREFUL board layout and impedance-controlled tracing.

Answer (score 3):

Since USB-C in that case only transports USB3 and M.2 only power and SATA, you could probably quite straightforwardly adapt open source hardware products like Olimex' [USB-SATA](https://www.olimex.com/Products/USB-Modules/USB-SATA/open-source-hardware) adapter or OSHW Lab's [sata usb converter](https://oshwlab.com/adrianbruchle/sata-usb-converter).

But especially the latter seems to be mostly a copy down from the reference design of an USB3 SATA controller's evaluation board design files – which aren't open source (as per any official definition of open source hardware, typically), but *meant to be adapted by you*, which might be even more relevant to you.

In that, case, [Texas Instruments TUSB9261](https://www.ti.com/product/TUSB9261) is the chip, and their eval board comes with free documentation.

The eval board comes with a full-sized SATA + SATA Power connector. SATA Power carries a whole range of different voltage rails that SSDs don't need. Unlike M.2, which, as far as I remember only carries a single 3.3V supply line – removing nearly all complexity of the power supply on that evaluation board, as you replace the SATA+SATA Power connector with a M.2 connector.

I don't think you need to implement an SMBUS host on these cards, I wouldn't know what for. Either way, just bring these pins out to holes where you can solder on a pin header, should you want to.

Happy hardware hacking!